# Trying to find the correct syntax for an when I need to take an if statement and check if the results are > 9 then add another if statement

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project for codecademy and am a little stuck on the syntax among other things ;). I am trying to reverse iterate an array and as I iterate to the left I need to double every other digit THEN check to see whether those numbers are greater than 9 after doubling them. THEN subtract the doubled number by 9. Any help would be much appreciated! This is my code so far

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3,
  invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5,];

// Add your functions below:

function validateCred(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
  if(i % 2 === 0) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] * 2;
  } else if (i % 2 === 1) {
    arr[i]
  }
 }
```

Comment: the first point wasn't clear, you said you want to iterate through the array and reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i]` by itself doesn't do anything, so you can just leave out the `else` statemennt.

After doubling the number, use an `if` statement to check if it's higher than `9`.

```js
function validateCred(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      arr[i] *= 2;
      if (arr[i] > 9) {
        arr[i] -= 9;
      }
    }
  }
}
```